# Light Box with Video

Tags: video

I need to show a lightbox slide show that will start with a video and once the video is complete it then rolls through static pictures on the slide show.  Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Chris Edwards

Answer (score 2):

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/ this is a lightbox that supports video

http://flowplayer.org/ this is a video player that supports the [lightbox](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) effect

video will have to hosted somewhere, for example http://youtube.com

What you want won't be easy to achieve, you can customize the flowplayer to swap some html and code with jquery when the video completes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few lightbox clones which allow you to open an iframe in the box rather than an image or other media. So you'd need to setup a page on your site which does what you're after, and then open that URL in the light box.

Here's a comparison table of the various light box clones available, hopefully you'll find one that's suitable:

http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/